# Format TextItem in SmartGWT 5.0 to show its numeric value in thousands

Tags: java, number-formatting, smartgwt

I have a `DynamicForm` with several `TextItem`s that contain numeric values (euros). It's required to add a checkbox that should switch the view mode of `TextItem`s from euros to thousands of euros and back (let's call it "Show in thousands" checkbox). But there is also a Submit button that should always be enabled. If the user clicks on this button, regardless of selected view mode, the value in euros (not in thousands of euros) should be saved to the server.

For example: we have `TextItem` with value of `100,000,500.33` euros. Once we switched to "show in thousands" view mode, the visible value should become `100,001`. But, if we click Submit button in this mode, the initial value (`100,000,500.33`) of the TextItem should be submitted to the server.

Moreover, "Show in thousands" checkbox should be checked by default.

I already tried to use `FormItem.setEditorValueFormatter(FormItemValueFormatter formatter)` but it did not really worked as expected.

Could you please help me to:

1. find some handler (formatter) to use with `TextItem` to be able to switch to/from "show in thousands" mode
2. enable "show in thousands" mode by default.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you need to handle this formatting of value by yourself only. Maybe inside `checkboxItem.addChangedHandler(...)`. On selection / unselection of "show in thousands".
2. `checkboxItem.setValue(true);` should work.